Getting Previous value partition wise in spark
I have an input table with columns: orderid, range, value1, value2 and value3
I want to create 3 new columns: previousvalue1, previousvalue2, previousvalue3 based on orderid and range
Here is the sample input and expected output:
Input:

Output:

I tried using .lag() function along with the window function - partition by orderid, range orderby range but it picked the last value from row one above within the same range, not the previous range.

can you post on your tables as formatted text and not images?

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? and Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?

Think of partitions as independent entities. There is no passing of values among the partitions (which is what you want in your output).
You need to apply conditions along with lag function based on the range column value and keep the orderid as the partition column as follows to get the correct output:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [
    (1, 100, 10),
    (1, 100, 10),
    (1, 150, 20),
    (1, 300, 40),
    (1, 200, 22),
    (1, 200, 22),
    (1, 400, 60),
    (2, 150, 10),
    (2, 150, 10),
    (2, 250, 15),
    (2, 300, 20),
    (2, 300, 20)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["orderid", "range", "value1"])

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("orderid").orderBy("range")

df = df.withColumn(
    "temp", 
    F.when(
        F.col("range") != F.lag("range").over(windowSpec),
        F.lag("value1").over(windowSpec)
    ).otherwise(None))

df = df.withColumn(
    "previousvalue1", 
    F.last("temp", ignorenulls=True).over(windowSpec)
).drop("temp")

df.show()

Output:
+-------+-----+------+--------------+
|orderid|range|value1|previousvalue1|
+-------+-----+------+--------------+
|      1|  100|    10|          NULL|
|      1|  100|    10|          NULL|
|      1|  150|    20|            10|
|      1|  200|    22|            20|
|      1|  200|    22|            20|
|      1|  300|    40|            22|
|      1|  400|    60|            40|
|      2|  150|    10|          NULL|
|      2|  150|    10|          NULL|
|      2|  250|    15|            10|
|      2|  300|    20|            15|
|      2|  300|    20|            15|
+-------+-----+------+--------------+

I am creating a temp column based on whether the lag value is the same as the current value in range. Then I fill the column using the last non-null value in temp for each partition.
You can repeat the same thing for the other two columns.
